# sqlite3. ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode

Tags: python, sqlite

I used the command below in my python code to update the data base

```
"""UPDATE  dbtest SET   id = ?, value = ? WHERE name=? ,("%s", "%s","%s")""" (data[0],data[1],data[2] )
```

`data[0],data[1],data[2]` where data is a list.
Python shows

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode
```

when running the script.
I am not able to figure out why the issue happens.

Comment: Is that the exact code? It looks like you've got superfluous data in the SQL string, and we can't see the full function call either...

Comment: What's teh content of `data`?

Comment: i think you are supposed to use `%` before the tuple?

Answer (score 1):

Your values list should be outside the SQL string, e.g.

```
db.execute("""UPDATE dbtest SET id = ?, value = ? WHERE name=?""", (data[0],data[1],data[2]))
```

Comment: cmd = """UPDATE SimulationParamDB SET enable= %d ,value = %s WHERE messagename = %s""" % ( int(data[1]), data[2],data[0]) and then  db.execute(cmd).  The data is having the string values.  When i execute this Python throws OperationalError: unrecognized token: "078ab291" where "078ab921" is data[2]

Comment: This is why ```?``` is preferred over ```%s```, as the engine will handle typed insertion, quoting, etc. As it stands, doing "...%s" % (...) is a SQL injection vector. So instead convert your arg types before passing them to execute: ```db.execute("""UPDATE dbtest SET id = ?, value = ? WHERE name=?""", (int(data[0]),data[1],data[2]))```

Comment: data = ['xyz','1','07b3450192043a23'].   I tried like this:  db.execute("""UPDATE db SET enable = ?, value = ? WHERE name = ?""",((int)(data[1]),data[2],data[0])).  But python throws   "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: You have some other problem; this works fine if you provide good inputs: `db.execute("""UPDATE dbtest SET enable = ?, value = ? WHERE name = ?""",((int)('1'),'07b3450192043a23' ,'xyz'))`